# How to get the Raw SQL Query with a Criteria Object?

Tags: shopware6

I'm fetching data using the Criteria object that comes from Shopware, but there are times when Shopware falls short and I need to use raw SQL queries. *E.g. I need to create nested queries.* What approach should I take for this? Is there any function or class for getting raw SQL query with Criteria object?

Comment: For now, I edit and use the codes in the search method of the EntitySearcher class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject `Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Dbal\CriteriaQueryBuilder` and retrieve an instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder` which would allow you to either use the abstraction or to get the raw SQL calling `getSQL`.

```php
$productDefinition = $container->get(ProductDefinition::class);
$criteria = new Criteria();
$query = new QueryBuilder($container->get(Connection::class));
$qb = $container->get(CriteriaQueryBuilder::class)->build($query, $productDefinition, $criteria, Context::createDefaultContext());
```

[Run it here](https://shopware.foo/o7Ouf1IUfB)

**However**: `CriteriaQueryBuilder` is marked `@internal` and as such you shouldn't rely on it, as there might be breaking changes even on minor releases. If Shopware's own database abstraction layer doesn't suit your needs, it would be arguably better, to use raw SQL from scratch, e.g. to fetch only the `id`s of certain entities. You could then use more complex subqueries and subsequently use the retrieved `id`s to fetch the entire complete entities.

```php
$ids = $container->get(Connection::class)->fetchFirstColumn('SELECT LOWER(HEX(`id`)) FROM `product` LIMIT 1');
$criteria = new Criteria($ids);

$product = $container->get('product.repository')->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->first();
```

[Run it here](https://shopware.foo/h3hnihLT3E)